# Delete substring not matching regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like:

```
'class="a", class="b", class="ab", class="body", class="etc"'
```

I want to delete everything except `class="a"` and `class="b"`.

How can I do it? I think the problem is easy but I'm stuck.

Here is some one of my attempts but it didn't solve my problem:

```
re.sub(r'class="also"|class="etc"', '', a)
```

My string is a very long HTML code with a lot of classes and I want to only keep two of them and drop all the others.
Some times its good to make a break. I found solution for me with bleach

```
def filter_class(name, value):
    if name == 'class' and value == 'aaa':
        return True

attrs = {
    'div': filter_class,
}
bleach.clean(html, tags=('div'), attributes=attrs, strip_comments=True)
```

Comment: Ok, i tried to do it with re.sub() but its good to delete substring if it match regex and also all other attempts is about if regex match substring its easy to delete.

Comment: post your re.sub command.

Comment: My question is....can't you just capture everything that matches and then join all the captured bits together?

Comment: Why you want to see my re.sub() ? here is some re.sub(r'class="also"|class="etc"', '', a) of my attempts but it didnt solve my problem

Comment: `My string is very long html code`, use html parsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried to explicitly enumerate those substrings you wanted to delete. Rather than writing such long patterns, you can just use *negative lookaheads* that provide a means to add exclusions to some more generic pattern.

Here is a regex you can use to remove those substrings in a clean way and disregarding order:

```
,? ?\bclass="(?![ab]")[^"]+"
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nS6iA8/2)

Here, with `(?![ab]")[^"]+`, we match 1 or more characters other than `"` (`[^"]+`), but not those equal to `a` or `b` (`(?![ab]")`).

Here is a sample code:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r',? ?\bclass="(?![ab]")[^"]+"')
test_str = "class=\"a\", class=\"b\", class=\"ab\", class=\"body\", class=\"etc\"\nclass=\"b\", class=\"ab\", class=\"body\", class=\"etc\", class=\"a\"\nclass=\"b\", class=\"ab\", class=\"body\", class=\"a\", class=\"etc\""
result = re.sub(p, '', test_str)
print(result)
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/OCzsHy)

**NOTE**: If instead of `a` and `b` you have longer sequences, use a `(?!(?:a|b)` non-capturing group in the look-ahead instead of a character class:

```
,? ?\bclass="(?!(?:arbuz|baklazhan)")[^"]+"
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/nS6iA8/4)

Comment: @DimonFirsov: Please have a look at my solution, I hope it'll be working for you fine.

Comment: Just a hint: use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for parsing HTML files, it is safer and much easier and more maintainable.

Comment: Yes i know about BS, but for me Bleach works well and when i faced this problem i decided to parse html before Bleach with regex. Right now i will look to BS mb if it has something like allowed clases i will switch for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you only wanted to keep the first two entries, one approach would be to use the `split()` function. This will split your string into a `list` at given separator points. In your case, this could be a comma. The first two list elements can then be joined back together with commas.

```
text = 'class="a", class="b", class="ab", class="body", class="etc"'
print ",".join(text.split(",")[:2])
```

Would give `class="a", class="b"`

If the entries can be anywhere, and for an arbitrary list of wanted classes:

```
def keep(text, keep_list):
    keep_set = set(re.findall("class\w*=\w*[\"'](.*?)[\"']", text)).intersection(set(keep_list))
    output_list = ['class="%s"' % a_class for a_class in keep_set]
    return ', '.join(output_list)

print keep('class="a", class="b", class="ab", class="body", class="etc"', ["a", "b"])
print keep('class="a", class="b", class="ab", class="body", class="etc"', ["body", "header"])
```

This would print:

```
class="a", class="b"
class="body"
```

Comment: Oh cmn if this solve my problem i did not post my question here. I got i got part of html page and i have some classes in it which i want to save and all others i want to drop.

Comment: @DimonFirsov Well don't whine about someone giving an answer to a really unclear question, then. No one knows what you're trying to ask.

Comment: Sry, my fault, tnx to everybody for helping

Answer (score 0):

another pretty simple solution.. good luck.

```
st = 'class="a", class="b", class="ab", class="body", class="etc"'
import re
res = re.findall(r'class="[a-b]"', st)
print res
'['class="a"', 'class="b"']'
```

you can use re.sub very easily

```
res = re.sub(r'class="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z].*"', "", st)
print res
class="a", class="b"
```

Comment: It is not a solution for the current problem, because you are *searching*, and OP needs *removing*.